# Display a progress bar while exe is running

Tags: exe, loading

In our company we have an exe that compares data from x files with a db. Whatever changed will be implemented into the db. What I would like to know is if it is possible to display a progress bar while the exe does what it does. I mean it's not taking forever, but I'd like to have any indication that it "started", that it's still "working on it" and to know how far it is in its work. Thank you.

I tried to google for a solution, but since I'm no developer I have no clue what to actually google and/or how to implement.

Comment: Are you looking to add this feature to the application itself?  (In which case, yes it's possible and would involve you modifying the code to the application.)  Or are you looking for some general tool which would somehow wrap an existing application to perform this task?  (In which case the question is off-topic, and I can't imagine how such a tool would even work.)

Comment: @David thank you for the reply. Well no, I wouldn't modify the file. I thought that since there are lets say 10 files, a full bar represents 10 files. So if the program deletes one filled the bar gets filled by 1/10. If 5 are deleted the bar is filed by 1/2 and so on, BUT I'm just speculating. I have no idea if this is possible.

Comment: So you're looking to write a program which monitors a known set of files and displays a progress bar based on some information from those files?  (Information including whether or not the files are still on the file system at all.)  That's possible, yes.  If that's the goal then I guess your next step would be to make an attempt.  Pretty much any programming language could be used for that, I imagine you'd take your pick based on what you're comfortable using and the ease of building whatever user interface you want to create. But either way, making an attempt is critical to building anything.